# How can i make a MouseMotionListener detect the end of a drag?

Tags: java

I have a MouseMotionListener and in the mouseDragged method I have a boolean that turns to true. The problem is I have no idea how to get it to turn back to false once the drag is over. Is there a way to do this?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is this for the purpose of Drag and Drop?

Answer (score 3):

for SWT: you could add a `MouseListener` with the method `public void mouseUp(MouseEvent arg0)` and set the boolean to false. See here: [MouseListener Example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/MouseListenerExample.htm)

Or if you use swing, this is helpful (with `public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e)`):
[MouseListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html)

Comment: The thing is though I'm not releasing the mouse, just "pausing" the drag, as in I drag, stop dragging, then continue all while having the button pressed. What happens right now is that the window will maintain momentum until i release the mouse. I'm looking to find out if there's a way to stop the drag without letting go of the mouse.

Comment: you could use a timer to check the mouse position during drag every ms or so, if the mouse position is the same for two checks, assume mouse move ended and set boolean. here is a reference for the timer of swing: [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html).

Comment: That's what I was thinking of doing. I just wanted to see if there was a more direct way. Thanks for the help

Comment: Maybe there is another way, but I can't think of any. It's not ideal, but will do the job...